# Change order of MySQL query keywords?

Tags: mysql

I'm using this 3rd party report generating software.  It has the following steps:

```
  1) insert your SQL statement into a webpage.  
  2) invoke an API to send the a set of primary keys to the Query
  3) A Report is generated.
```

Unfortunately, the software is dumb, and simply appends the WHERE clause after the SQL statement.  However with MySQL the WHERE statement is supposed to be before the GROUP BY.   So when the API appends a WHERE it fails because its invalid SQL.  Is there some way to tell MySQL to expect the WHERE statement at the end?

```
select incident.incidentID,
GROUP_CONCAT(moccode2.Description) as MOC2Description 
from incident
join incidentmoc on incident.IncidentID = incidentmoc.IncidentID
inner join moccode2 on moccode2.id = incidentmoc.moccodeid
/* WHERE should go here */ 
group by incident.incidentID
/* I want the WHERE to go here */
```

Derek Kromm is basically correct in what I asked for, unfortunately I have additional constraints.  It's still going to append the WHERE.

So I tried this:

```
 select incident.incidentID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(moccode2.Description) as MOC2Description 
    from incident
    join incidentmoc on incident.IncidentID = incidentmoc.IncidentID
    inner join moccode2 on moccode2.id = incidentmoc.moccodeid
    group by incident.incidentID
    HAVING incident.IncidentID > 1
   ////////////////////////////////////////
    now software appends WHERE invalid SQL
```

Comment: What's the report generating software? I'd like to make note of that so I can tell my boss to avoid it...

Comment: @jwiscarson eWebReports is the software

Comment: I guess it was my fault.  So their software isn't too blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` keyword

This link has some details around using it: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx